# How to validate a domain exists from the browser?

Tags: javascript, email-validation

We have been getting a lot of people signup up with invalid email domain names eg:

```
gmail.cim
hotmale.com
```

I'm looking to find out if there is a method which can reliably validate if the domain section of an email address is a valid domain and if it exists.

I understand that this is possible from any backend, but I was wondering if there is a method which would work from inside the browser?

I do understand that there are methods via a regex to validate that a domain is possible, but they do not fit this particular use case.

Comment: I'm pretty sure `hotmale.com` exists, though I probably shouldn't check while at work...

Comment: @kmoe               nice one xD .... but lets work on the issue :P

Comment: Anything that happens on the user's side, that is, in the browser, can easily be faked or spoofed, any real checking will have to take place in your back-end. Once you have a working back-end you can just call to it over Ajax.

Comment: http://sphinx.mythic-beasts.com/~pdw/cgi-bin/emailvalidate you need to hack this

Comment: You can whitelist the recurring domains, but the most efficient client side verification is to double check email address on registration and send validation email

Comment: @Nit I am aware of this, and we are putting server side verification on domains. But we wanted to integrate a check for valid domains in with our client side verification. Our primary demographic is the elderly and we want to give them as much feedback as possible. I agree that an ajax call from the client to the server would be easiest. But I was specifically looking for a method from the browser.

Comment: @AnantDabhi I would prefer not to abuse someone's service, also this requires the backend. I am looking for a client side javascript solution.

Comment: but if u want to validate any email address you need to use third party service to check whether the email-id is exists or not..

Answer (score 0):

You could validate it with a list , store the list of possible domain names in an array .
Once you a get a input (get the characters after `@`) , traverse through the array.
Check for the valid inputs .

But the best way would be prompting the user to check with the subscription mail

Hope this helps !!

Comment: This doesn't work for new users with domains that I have not specifically white-listed. This is a surprisingly common occurrence and should be avoided.

Answer (score -1):

You can create a list of valid domains. This link http://www.checkdomain.com/list.html contains the list.

And you can compare the user's domain with the available valid domains.

Comment: This list doesn't contain .aero, .sexy, .cafe, .blog or any non-geographic TLD's. It would also allow example.com to pass the validation. It is therefore unsuitable

Answer (score -1):

To validate email/email confirm fields, use Jquery validate:

```
$('#myForm').validate({
  rules: {
    email: 'required',
    emailConfirm: {
        equalTo: '#email'
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: This does not validate the domain exists. Read the question again

Comment: I did understand, in my comment below I propose whitlisting some domains (this solution is limited) but the example you give seems to be typing errors so what I propose is to make the user verify his email twice before submitting

Comment: @radia that's fair enough and we do expect that it is to do with typing errors. I was looking for a solution that uses the DNS system in some manner.

Comment: there are no client side solutions for this, all you can do is to check that email address is correctly-formatted